# What is the minimum $a_{100}$?

Tags: optimization, recreational-mathematics

> $100$ integers $a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_{100}$ satisfy the following conditions
>
> - $0 < a_1 < a_2 < \cdots < a_{100}$.
> - if $i < j$ then, $a_j \div a_i \neq 2$.
>
> What is the minimum $a_{100}$ ?

The answer is less than or equal to 149:

```
1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 23, 25, 27, 28, 29, 31, 33, 35, 36, 37, 39, 41, 43, 44, 45, 47, 48, 49, 51, 52, 53, 55, 57, 59, 60, 61, 63, 64, 65, 67, 68, 69, 71, 73, 75, 76, 77, 79, 80, 81, 83, 84, 85, 87, 89, 91, 92, 93, 95, 97, 99, 100, 101, 103, 105, 107, 108, 109, 111, 112, 113, 115, 116, 117, 119, 121, 123, 124, 125, 127, 129, 131, 132, 133, 135, 137, 139, 140, 141, 143, 144, 145, 147, 148, 149
```

My conjecture is 149.

Comment: One could quite easily make a computer program and let it run. But 1) I don't have access to a computer right now, and 2) this looks like a really cool extremal combinatorics problem and if there is an elegant theoretical answer I would very much enjoy reading it.

Comment: @Arthur: you say "quite easily", but I don't see it. What is your strategy for avoiding an exponential running time?

Comment: @TonyK I didn't say one can quite easily make a _fast_ computer program. Also, I have realised that the number of sequences to check is quite a bit bigger than what is feasible. So, all in all, scratch that thought.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the pigeon hole principle.
Assume by contradiction that $1\leq a_{1}<\cdots<a_{100}\leq 148$. Cover the set $\{1,2,\ldots,148\}$ by the holes

{1,2}, {3,6}, {4,8}, {5,10}, {7,14}, {9,18}, {11,22}, ...,
{65,130}, {67,134}, {68,136}, {69,138}, {71,142}, {73,146},
{75}, {76}, {77}, {79},..., {145}, {147}, {148}.

(i.e. take elements in $\{1,\ldots, 148\}$ that differ by a factor $2$, then add the elements that you did not pick yet).

You will see that there are exactly $99$ holes. As there are $100$ elements $a_{i}$, there must exist $a_{i}< a_{j}$ that lie in the same hole. This implies that $a_{j}=2a_{i}$, contrary to the assumption. So the minimum $a_{100}$ is indeed $149$.

Answer (score 2):

Let us work from the top down instead. Suppose we are given an upper bound $A\geq a_i$. Then for any odd number $x\leq A$ we may define $s$ to be the maximal exponent such that
$$
2^sx\leq A
$$
If $s$ is odd we can at most include the numbers $2^1x,2^3x,...,2^sx$ among our choices for $a_i$. That makes $(s+1)/2$ numbers. If $s$ is even we can include $2^0x,2^2x,...,2^sx$ which makes $(s+2)/2$ numbers.

The exponents $s$ can be found for any given odd $x\leq A$ using the formula
$$
s=\lfloor\log_2(A/x)\rfloor
$$
so the most numbers we will be able to fit in given the bound $A$ must be
$$
\max_i(A)=\sum_{x\leq A}^{x\text{ odd}}f(\lfloor\log_2(A/x)\rfloor)
$$
where $f(s)=(s+1)/2$ if $s$ is odd and $f(s)=(s+2)/2$ if $s$ is even.

---

Computing this sum for $A=148$ and $A=149$ one obtains
$$
\max_i(148)=99\quad\text{and}\quad\max_i(149)=100
$$
so indeed $a_{100}=149$ is optimal.

Comment: This proof is not complete. You still have to show that if $x>y$, then $\max_i(x)\ge\max_i(y)$.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud: OK, but isn't it obvious that you cannot fill in more numbers to a smaller space?

Comment: It's reasonable, but I've learned to never exclude the possibility to be surprised until I have a formal proof.